# Ruby pitfall with SimpleDelegator

Tags: ruby, delegates

I recently added some code to a class hierarchy that included `SimpleDelegator`, with surprising results.  Boiled down to its simplest form, the code looked like this:

```
class Query
  def size; 10; end
  def container; QueryContainer.new(self); end
end

class WrappedQuery < SimpleDelegator
  def size; 99; end
end

class QueryContainer
  def initialize(query); @query = query; end
  def how_many; @query.size; end
end

query = Query.new
wrapped = WrappedQuery.new(Query.new)

puts query.container.how_many    # prints 10
puts wrapped.container.how_many  # also prints 10 (!)
```

This issue took a lot of effort to track down.  It happens because calls to `container` on a `WrappedQuery` object are forwarded to the wrapped instance, resulting in a `QueryContainer` object that contains the wrapped instance, not the original `WrappedQuery` object.  So, the container contains an object with the wrong `size` attribute.

I introduced the issue by adding a default `container` method to the `Query` base class, and a different implementation to a particular subclass.  Unbeknownst to me, a different team in my company was using `Query` objects that were wrapped in a `SimpleDelegator`, and my code was inadvertently unwrapping them.

My eventual fix was to do what I've been calling "manual polymorphism":

```
class Query
  def self.container_for(query)
    case query
    when QuerySubclass
      SpecificContainer.new(query)
    else
      Container.new(query)
    end
  end
end
```

This looks really awkward though.

Since I introduced a production issue with my change, I've been tasked with coming up with a way to prevent it from happening again.  I'm having a hard time coming up with any concrete ideas, though.  My change still seems totally innocuous: add a default method to a base class, and a more specific method to a subclass.  But the presence of `SimpleDelegator` throws a wrench into things.

What are some general style guidelines I could recommend be adopted that would prevent this kind of problem in the future?  All I can really think of are:

- Disallow completely general delegators like `SimpleDelegator`
- Don't allow methods that return objects that wrap `self`

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 2):

Remember the behaviour of `SimpleDelegator` is that the decorator class automatically forwards any missing method to the wrapped class. In your case:

```
class WrappedQuery < SimpleDelegator
  def size; 99; end
end
```

does not define a `container()` method. So when you call `wrapped.container...` it passes execution to `Query::container()`, where of course `self` points at the 'wrapped' `Query` object.

If you duplicate the `container()` method in the `WrappedQuery` class, it will do what you expected initially and return the `SimpleDelegator`.

Comment: I get that this is one way to solve my immediate problem, but my question isn't about that, it's about how to assure that this type of issue doesn't occur again in my company's codebase.  Some kind of general coding standard.  "Design all classes with an eye towards what would happen if an instance was wrapped in a SimpleDelegator" would work, but is so intrusive as to be unworkable.  "Only use SimpleDelegator in circumstances X, Y, or Z" is better, but I don't know what X, Y, or Z should be.

Comment: I guess if you're searching for a guideline it would be 'don't use ``SimpleDelegator`` when you should be subclassing'. The ``Decorator`` pattern is for dynamically extending the behaviour of a class at runtime. Your example might be simplified, but as-is it looks more like the ``WrappedQuery`` should just inherit ``Query``.

Answer (score 1):

> My change still seems totally innocuous: add a default method to a base class, and a more specific method to a subclass. But the presence of `SimpleDelegator` throws a wrench into things.

`SimpleDelegator` doesn't (and shouldn't) alter the inner workings of `Query`. If you want the behavior of a subclass, then maybe you should simply make `WrappedQuery` a subclass of `Query`:

```
class Query
  def size; 10; end
  def container; QueryContainer.new(self); end
end

class WrappedQuery < Query
  def size; 99; end
end

class QueryContainer
  def initialize(query); @query = query; end
  def how_many; @query.size; end
end

query = Query.new
wrapped = WrappedQuery.new

query.container.how_many    #=> 10
wrapped.container.how_many  #=> 99
```